# Replacing Tall Baseboards with Smaller Baseboard

Tags: drywall, walls, trim, baseboard

I am installing new baseboards along my walls but the baseboard I removed was really tall (probably about 5 inches). The new base moulding is only about 3 1/4 inches tall. The walls where the baseboard was removed looks like this:

[image]

How should I make sure that seam doesn't show once I put the moulding up and paint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's too late to consider 5-1/4" trim?

Hit the line of old caulk with a long blade utility knife (like an Olfa), a sharp chisel or a wallpaper scraper. Then sand lightly to knock down any other lumps and apply a coat or two of mud. (Premixed if you have time; 20 or 90 minute setting compound if you're in a hurry.) When dry, sand lightly.